# Instanceof com List em JAVA

Tags: java, lista

Declarei um método que recebe um `List` do tipo `Object`. Porém, quando vou tentar reconhecer ele com `instanceof` ele dá erro. Já tentei fazer um casting mas continua dando erro e não consegui identificar onde está o problema no meu código. Alguém pode ajudar?

```
public static void insertLog(List<Object> list) throws IOException{

    if (list instanceof List<Transaction>){
        for(Transaction transaction : list){
            insertLog(transaction.toString());
        }
    }

    else if (list instanceof List<Data>){
        for(Data data : list){
            insertLog(data.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

```
public static void insertLog(CashTransactionRequest request) throws IOException{
    insertLog(request.getClient().getCustomer());
    insertLog(request.getClient().getTeller());
    insertLog(request.getClient().getTellerName());

    insertLog(request.getDevice().getCountryId());
    insertLog(request.getDevice().getDelegation());
    insertLog(request.getDevice().getDeviceId());
    insertLog(request.getDevice().getDeviceName());
    insertLog(request.getDevice().getDeviceType());
    insertLog(request.getDevice().getTimeZone());

    insertLog(request.getAdditionalData().getData());

    insertLog(request.getTransaction());
}
```

Comment: Pode dizer qual erro que é ?

Comment: Em Java, não é guardada a referência do generics. Então, o Java não tem como dizer a diferença entre `List<Banana> ` de `List<Laranja>`. Então você pode acabar misturando bananas com laranjas se não tiver cuidado

Comment: Pode adicionar o código da duvida?

Comment: Ademais, prefira publicar código à imagem. Eu até tentaria fazer uma correção no que você escreveu, mas como está em imagem não tem como copiar e colar. Inclusive, o fato de ter usado imagens e não códigos pode ser o motivo do voto negativo

Comment: Se você vai usar o `toString` não tem porque fazer casting

Comment: Veja isso: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer a verificação pelo item ao invés da lista:

```
public static void insertLog(List list) {
  for (Object item : list) {
    if (item instanceof Transaction) {
      insertLog((Transaction) item);
    } else if (item instanceof Data) {
      insertLog((Data) item);
    }
  }
}
```

Notei que no seu exemplo você utiliza `String`. Para fazer o `toString` não é necessário realizar conversão, então também não é necessário realizar a verificação.

Answer (score 4):

`List<Transaction>` não é uma `List<Object>`. `List<Data>` também não é uma `List<Object>`. O motivo é que em um `List<Object>` você pode adicionar qualquer objeto, enquanto que em um `List<Transaction>` você só pode adicionar objetos do tipo `Transaction`. No `List<Data>` você só pode adicionar objetos `Data`.

Todo objeto tem um método `getClass()` que retorna um outro objeto (do tipo `Class`) que representa a classe do objeto. Se você fizer isso:

```
List<Transaction> lista1 = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
System.out.println(lista1.getClass().getName());
List<Data> lista2 = new ArrayList<Data>();
System.out.println(lista2.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(lista1.getClass() == lista2.getClass());
```

Ele vai imprimir:

```
java.util.ArrayList
java.util.ArrayList
true
```

Ou seja, ambas as listas têm o mesmo tipo. O genérico não importa.

O operador `instanceof` olha para a classe do `getClass()`. O genérico é perdido nesse caso. Ou seja, não adianta fazer `instanceof List<Transaction>` ou `instanceof List<Data>`, pois o `instanceof` não enxerga os genéricos e vê apenas `List`.

Por que você não faz apenas isso?

```
public static void insertLog(List<Object> list) throws IOException {
    for (Object item : list) {
        insertLog(item.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Na [resposta do @Sorack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238251/64969), ele fornece duas alternativas de como tratar a questão. A [resposta do @VictorStafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238254/64969) fornece mais detalhes e oferece a solução via `toString()` mencionada pelo @Sorack. Vou propor algo aqui um pouco mais voltado ao funcional.

> PS: um pouco mais voltado porque poderia ser muito bem tratado de maneira mais idiomática, porém como estou longe de um computador não tenho como validar

Suponha que você saiba como inserir no *log* uma informação `E` qualquer. Pode ser `Logger.insertData` para objetos do tipo `Data` e `Logger.insertTransaction` para objetos do tipo `Transaction`.

```
public static <E> void insertLog(List<E> list, Consumer<E> logAtom) throws IOException {
  list.forEach(logAtom::accept);
}


// exemplo de chamada
public static void insertLog() {
  List<Transaction> transacoes = getTransacoes();
  insertLog(transacoes, Logger::insertTransaction);

  List<Data> datas = getDatas();
  insertLog(datas, Logger::insertData);
}
```